# Elasticsearch MAC 10.14.6 with Java jdk-12.0.2.jdk main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ESJsonLayout

Tags: java, macos, elasticsearch

I installed on my Mac OS 14.0.6 Elasticsearch with brew. It must be ES V 6 - not 7. But I tied to install 7 too - same error.
So must be problem with the jdk?
After all was running well, I start with command `elasticsearch` and I get the following error in console:

JAVA VERSION:
java -version
java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

````
2019-08-19 20:19:13,173 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ESJsonLayout
2019-08-19 20:19:13,173 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ESJsonLayout
2019-08-19 20:19:13,174 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ESJsonLayout
2019-08-19 20:19:13,202 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for ESJsonLayout
2019-08-19 20:19:13,219 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:87)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:181)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:234)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:127)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:302)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)

2019-08-19 20:19:13,222 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
.......and on .... ```

I tried different reinstalls, but nothing works. Some help will be nice.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the same problem after remove v7 and install v6. Solving this by manual remove ES configs and reinstall ES

```
brew remove elasticsearch

rm -fR `brew --prefix`/etc/elasticsearch

brew install elasticsearch
```

Comment: also remove `/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/`